# How to work on multiple canvas sizes non-destructively

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, batch-processing

I am working on a UI project that requires multiple scales.

Essentially I want to work at a high resolution(the original) but I need to be able to export the different widgets all at the same lower resolution(for size purposes).

Because I have to export each widget manually(I suppose a script could handle all this very nicely) and at a reduced size, it is very time consuming.

The process is as follows:

1. Select Layer bounds selection(Ctrl-Click layer)
2. Crop
3. Resize/scale/reduce resolution
4. Export
5. Undo
6. Repeat for next widget.

I have to do this for every widget and every time I make changes. It is very time consuming and there has to be a better way.

I was thinking I could use a smart layer then transform it by scaling. That might only remove step 3 though. I still have to resize the canvas/crop,

Any ideas?

If a script is the right way to go, anyone smart enough to throw one together quickly for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Using `File` > `Save for web..` you can specify the output size regardless of the canvas size inside your PSD. Work at the highest resolution and then just save it at all the different resolutions from that one file, using save for web.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways of doing this but this is the quickest I've found

- Right-click on a layer or layer group and select `Export As...`
- Change the scale to 50% and set format options
- Hit `Export All...`

There's a specific function for exporting assets at different pixel densities in the top left of this dialog, but it looks like it's designed for people editing @1x and scaling up rather than down.